# How to group timestamps by labels?

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe(Series) indexed by DatetimeIndex

```
                    tag
2015-08-21 16:32:00 stationary
2015-08-21 16:33:00 automotive
2015-08-21 16:34:00 automotive
2015-08-21 17:27:00 stationary
2015-08-21 17:28:00 stationary
2015-08-21 17:29:00 stationary
2015-08-21 17:30:00 stationary
2015-08-21 17:31:00 stationary
2015-08-21 17:32:00 stationary
2015-08-24 16:55:00 automotive
2015-08-24 16:56:00 automotive
2015-08-24 16:57:00 automotive
2015-08-24 16:58:00 automotive
2015-08-24 16:59:00 stationary
2015-08-24 17:00:00 stationary
2015-08-24 17:01:00 stationary
```

want to groupby tag and aggregate time index, so the expected result is

```
Start                       End                 Tag
-                           2015-08-21 16:32:00 stationary
2015-08-21 16:34:00         2015-08-21 16:34:00 automotive
2015-08-21 17:27:00         2015-08-21 17:32:00 stationary
2015-08-24 16:55:00         2015-08-24 16:58:00 automotive
2015-08-24 16:59:00         2015-08-24 17:01:00 stationary
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `groupby` and `apply` scheme.

```
def func(group):
    return pd.Series({'Start': group.index[0], 'End': group.index[-1], 'Tag': group['tag'].values[0]})

df.groupby((df.shift(1) != df).cumsum()['tag'], as_index=False).apply(func)

                   End                Start         Tag
0  2015-08-21 16:32:00  2015-08-21 16:32:00  stationary
1  2015-08-21 16:34:00  2015-08-21 16:33:00  automotive
2  2015-08-21 17:32:00  2015-08-21 17:27:00  stationary
3  2015-08-24 16:58:00  2015-08-24 16:55:00  automotive
4  2015-08-24 17:01:00  2015-08-24 16:59:00  stationary
```

Comment: Very elegant.
However, tested on big dataframes, it seems to perform really slower: 
9 seconds versus 90 ms using my answer on 10000 rows.

Comment: @Omar agreed. This specific `groupby` operation involves iterating over too many subgroups and building a new `pd.Series` in each group introduces a lot overhead if the function is called so many times (in case that the tag changes so frequently). Your approach is completely based on vectorized `numpy.array` and is much faster in this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure your expected result was correct, here is what I think the correct expected result is:

```
    begin   end     tag
0   2015-08-21 16:32:00     2015-08-21 16:32:00     stationary
1   2015-08-21 16:33:00     2015-08-21 16:34:00     automotive
3   2015-08-21 17:27:00     2015-08-21 17:32:00     stationary
9   2015-08-24 16:55:00     2015-08-24 16:58:00     automotive
13  2015-08-24 16:59:00     2015-08-24 17:01:00     stationary
```

And here is how to obtain it:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
# Prepare data from your example
data = [
("2015-08-21 16:32:00", "stationary"),
("2015-08-21 16:33:00", "automotive"),
("2015-08-21 16:34:00", "automotive"),
("2015-08-21 17:27:00", "stationary"),
("2015-08-21 17:28:00", "stationary"),
("2015-08-21 17:29:00", "stationary"),
("2015-08-21 17:30:00", "stationary"),
("2015-08-21 17:31:00", "stationary"),
("2015-08-21 17:32:00", "stationary"),
("2015-08-24 16:55:00", "automotive"),
("2015-08-24 16:56:00", "automotive"),
("2015-08-24 16:57:00", "automotive"),
("2015-08-24 16:58:00", "automotive"),
("2015-08-24 16:59:00", "stationary"),
("2015-08-24 17:00:00", "stationary"),
("2015-08-24 17:01:00", "stationary")]
data = [(datetime.strptime(x[0], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), x[1]) for x in data]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['ts', 'tag']).sort('ts')
df['is_first'] = df.tag != df.tag.shift()
df['is_last'] = df.tag != df.tag.shift(-1)
# Fill begin timestamp, only on first occurences
df['begin'] = df.ts
df.loc[~df.is_first, 'begin'] = pd.NaT
# Fill end timestamp, only on last occurences
df['end'] = df.ts
df.loc[~df.is_last, 'end'] = pd.NaT
# Fill NaT with next end
df['end'] = df['end'].bfill()
# Restrict to changes
df = df[df.is_first]
# Remove useless columns
df = df[['begin', 'end', 'tag']].sort('begin')
```